# English-Czech Decimal Problems

Tags: .net, vb.net, sqlite, localization, decimal

I'm sure this question has been answered before, but sometimes I need to ask it in my own words to understand the answer.

I ran into an issue recently where a person with Czech language being used on their computer would could not run my application, I use US-English.

I have some decimal values saved as a string in an SQLite database. I guess the Czech language does not like my decimals(1.50) because it crashes when trying to parse it from string to decimal. It just doesn't recognize 1.50 as the correct format for a decimal.

I'm hoping for an easy fix, someone suggested forcing Localization Culture to en-US. I did a little research and got really confused, I was hoping someone could help me understand how to solve this issue.

Thank you

Loading the SQLite data:

```
    Public Shared Sub LoadAutoBetting()
    Dim SQLstr As String = "Select * FROM AutoBetting"
    Dim connection As String = "Data Source=utb.db;Version=3"
    Dim SQLConn As New SQLiteConnection
    Dim SQLcmd As New SQLiteCommand
    Dim SQLdr As SQLiteDataReader
    SQLConn.ConnectionString = connection
    SQLConn.Open()
    SQLcmd.Connection = SQLConn
    SQLcmd.CommandText = SQLstr
    SQLdr = SQLcmd.ExecuteReader()
    While SQLdr.Read()
        Bets.autoMulti = SQLdr(0)
    End While
    SQLdr.Close()
    SQLConn.Close()
End Sub
```

The error pops at `Bets.autoMulti = SQLdr(0)` autoMulti is a decimal, SQLdr(0) is a string(1.50) which is a default value that I inserted when I created the table.

Comment: Dont force it to English, parse it based on the local culture - show what you are doing

Comment: Plutonix, I updated the post with the code where the data is loaded with irrelevant code removed. Do you need to see anything else?

Comment: I should mention that I have tried `Decimal.Parse(SQLdr(0))` & `CDec(SQLdr(0))`

Comment: `autoMulti is a decimal, SQLdr(0) is a string(1.50)` that actuals begs more questions.  A) It sounds like Option Strict is off because assigning a string to a Decimal would not be allowed B) if the value is Decimal, why save it as string?  `Decimal.TryParse(strD, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, dec)` this will parse it (or try) respecting the local computer culture setting - that it, allow `.` for english, and `,` for much of the rest of the world.  Again, if you save as a numeric you wont have to parse it

Comment: Because in SQLite I only have the option to save data as text or integer. If I try saving as integer I lose my decimal, so I save it as text.

Comment: You might want to know that you can activate a Language Bar/Culture Picker (see Regional settings) so that you can flip between cultures easily for testing.  Its a pick list in the system tray.  Great for testing

Comment: Josh, sqlite3 supports the REAL datatype to store this kind of data.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I think the best thing for me to do is simply not set a decimal as a default value, just use a whole number and let their system set the decimal if they want one.

Comment: If a CZ decimal (say `1,50`) gets saved as `"1.50"` there would have to be code somewhere formatting it to include the Dot.  A decimal *value* has no culture and a saved CZ or FR *value* can be read it perfectly by EN or any other culture.  The decimal points are the way it is formatted for the user based on their culture.  Save them as REAL or change to MySQL which has a much more robust set of datatypes and you wont have to worry. `Dim myDec As Decimal = 1.49D` will be valid, it will just be displayed differently based on the culture.

Answer (score 0):

I made the experience that vb relies heavily on windows regional settings. Likely it expects a ',' as decimal separator. This is not only the case in czech republic. It's common in europe. The same problem pops up when working with date formats (dd/mm/YYYY, dd.mm.YYYY, mm/dd/YYYY, YYYY-mm-dd, ...).

You could write your own function for parsing the string in the sql query result according to regional settings.

Answer (score -1):

Make the culture explicit, both in writing decimals to strings and when reading them back. Good choice might be "InvariantCulture" , which in fact is US.

When you rely on the "current" culture (on the PC) you're asking for trouble as you can't know what a potential user in the future may choose.